# change text to image and back on button at runtime in Android

Tags: android, button

I want to change a button's text to an image, and back (instead the image I want the text back) on some user interactions, at RUNTIME.
How can I do this? Can anyone show me an example?

As far as I understood I can't use Image Button, because I can't add text on it.
I tried to use

```
setCompoundDrawables
```

but this is not working for me (no visible change on button). Here is my code:

```
 Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

 Drawable myDrawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
 myDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, 0, 0);

 button.setCompoundDrawables(myDrawable, null, null, null);
```

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is the problem

```
myDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

Since you've given `0` for `left, top, right, bottom`, there is no visible change. Try to give some values like `10` or `15` for the `right` and `bottom`, and you'll be able to see the change.